# Downloading solution manual of books

Tags: copyright

For many textbooks solution manuals are available online. Is it copyright violation to download these manuals for studying?

Comment: Yes if it is a solution manual written by the author of the book. In that case it has the same copyright protections as the original book.

Answer (score 2):

It is copyright infringement unless the author of the solution manual gives permission. The author of the textbook has no say in the matter. A solution manual might happen to infringe the textbook's copyright, e.g is the manual included the question along with the solution, provided that the question itself is protected by copyright.

If the author puts his manual of solutions out in the open on his web page, he would not succeed in suing you for downloading the book, since by putting the work out in the open, he has invited the compelling conclusion that you are permitted to see what he has shown (otherwise, one could never legally look at a web site). However, a work pirated by a third party and displayed on a pirate site like libgen conveys no implicit license from the author, which is why I framed this in terms of the manual author's own web page.

Comment: Technically, it's the copyright-holder (normally the publisher) not the author who must give permission (at least in common-law countries, copyright law in some places is a bit different). The author may have assigned their rights to someone else, or may have been commissioned to write the book as an employee and thus never have owned the copyright.